# Annotation box does not appear in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

The planned annotation box does not appear on my plot, however, I've tried a wide range of values for its coordinates.

What's wrong with that?!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(s,t):
    a = 0.7
    b = 0.8
    Iext= 0.5
    tau = 12.5
    v = s[0]
    w = s[1]
    dndt = v - np.power(v,3)/3 - w + Iext
    dwdt = (v + a - b * w)/tau
    return [dndt, dwdt]

t = np.linspace(0,200)
s0=[1,1]

s = odeint(f,s0,t)

plt.plot(t,s[:,0],'b-', linewidth=1.0)
plt.xlabel(r"$t(sec.)$")
plt.ylabel(r"$V (volt)$")
plt.legend([r"$V$"])

annotation_string = r"$I_{ext}=0.5$" 
plt.text(15, 60, annotation_string, bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coordinates to `plt.text` are data coordinates by default. This means in order to be present in the plot they should not exceed the data limits of your plot (here, ~0..200 in x direction, ~-2..2 in y direction).

Something like `plt.text(10,1.8)` should work.

The problem with that is that once the data limits change (because you plot something different or add another plot) the text item will be at a different position inside the canvas.

If this is undesired, you can specify the text in axes coordinates (ranging from 0 to 1 in both directions). In order to place the text always in the top left corner of the axes, independent on what you plot there, you can use e.g.

```
plt.text(0.03,0.97, annotation_string, bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5), 
         transform=plt.gca().transAxes, va = "top", ha="left")
```

Here the `transform` keyword tells the text to use Axes coordinates, and `va = "top", ha="left"` means, that the top left corner of the text should be the anchor point.

Comment: Typo:  ha='left'.

Comment: There is a simpler way to do this with out having to (directly) use `transform` http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations.html#basic-annotation use `textcoords` and `xycoords`.

Comment: @tacaswell "Simple" in what respect? Using `annotate` to create a text field like here requires to set more arguments and to type more charaters.  Plus (but that may be personal taste), I can easily remember `ax.transAxes` while for the strings to supply to `textcoords` and `xycoords` I always need to look up whether its "axes"  or "axes fraction" or "axes coords" or whatever other string to use here. Is there any drawback of using the transform? I would guess that those sting flags simply set the transform internally, right?

Comment: The `offset *` values are trickier to do with strait transforms.   For example 'right align top align text 50 pixels from the top right corner of the axes' is easy to to with `annotate`.

Comment: @tacaswell That is true, it would otherwise require and additional transform so you'd need to import transforms etc. Btw, what I find really annoying is that you cannot manipulate the text box' bounding box, like e.g. the legend's bounding box (using `bbox_to_anchor`). As the text's FancyBox padding is in units of fontsize (or something strange) you always need a complete set of transform steps to align the box to something.

Answer (score 1):

The annotation is appearing far above your plot because you have given a 'y' coordinate of 60, whereas your plot ends at '2' (upwards).

Change the second argument here:

```
plt.text(15, 60, annotation_string, bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5))
```

It needs to be <=2 to show up on the plot itself. You may also want to change the x coorinate (from 15 to something less), so that it doesn't obscure your lines.

e.g.

```
plt.text(5, 1.5, annotation_string, bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5))
```

Don't be alarmed by my (5,1.5) suggestion, I would then add the following line to the top of your script (beneath your imports):

```
rcParams['legend.loc'] = 'best'
```

This will choose a 'best fit' for your legend; in this case, top left (just above your annotation). Both look quite neat then, your choice though :)